# Android Eclipse SharedPreferences location again

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've looked at all of the threads on this that I could find and none of them really have explained why the file can't be found, so I'm trying again with code. I ran this on my LG Spectrum in the debugger. It all works fine except there is no file created that I can find, plus I can't read the name/value pair that I wrote.

```
package com.example.locdir;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int testint = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setup();
    readback();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setup() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("testint", 475);
    editor.commit();        
}

private void readback() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int testint = sharedPref.getInt("testint", 0);
}
}
```

According to debugger behavior, it goes well. The value of sharedPref.mFile.path is "/data/data/com.example.locdir/shared_prefs/locdir_pref.xml"

After running, there is no file there by this name on this path.

When the readback method is called and the getInt happens, testint is still 0.

There were no log complaints that I could see.

Oh, and I tried sharedPref.apply() also. Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the variable `int testint = 0` at the beginning of your class. Remove that line and everything should work fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int testint = 0; // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you monitor testint. If it is in onCreate() method, yes you will have 0 no matter what because you have define testint as a global variable and initialize it with 0.
Change your code as follows.

```
private void readback() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    testint = sharedPref.getInt("testint", 0); // remove int
}
}
```

Comment: It also helped. See above. Problem with both of these answers so far is that I still can't find the file using a file manager app. Is int hidden and I'm beating my head against a wall? It's not so much that it matters for this test program here, but I'm having similar issues on a bigger app I'm working on. I wish I could vote for both of these answers. Not enough points. :)